"差し引いて"? What does it mean?
起き上がろうとした肩を、強い力で押し返される。
自分の視界は呆気なく、再び天井を向かされた。
目覚めたばかりの脱力を差し引いて、彼の柔道的な技だ。
懐中電灯が転がった。
The character woke up after being knocked out. He finds someone pointing a torch at him. As far I can see, he tries to get up, but he's knocked down again.
自分の視界は呆気なく、再び天井を向かされた。
My gaze ended up staring at the selling over too soon.
目覚めたばかりの脱力を差し引いて、彼の柔道的な技だ。
Then he explains I guess that the person used a judo technique.  What I'm curious is, what does を差し引いて here mean? Is he saying the person took away his streght with a judo technique? Or is it more "setting aside x"?
